# Scala 2.10 - Output of SQL to Key Value Pair

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I have an output that is coming from Spark SQL as rows and column values. I want to convert this into a Key Value pair so that it can be written as a Sequence file into HDFS.

```
argmappeddata.registerTempTable("loanstbl")
```

SparkSQL is

```
select purpose, count(*), sum(total_pymnt) as tot_pymnt 
from loanstbl group by purpose
```

The output from is something like the following

```
Map(total_pymnt -> 7709668.451690674, purpose -> moving, cnt -> 2420)
Map(total_pymnt -> 8807398.730529785, purpose -> house, cnt -> 1438)
Map(total_pymnt -> 1.1700618113235474E7, purpose -> car, cnt -> 3466)
```

I am new to Scala programming and hence please pardon if this is very basic.

Thanks

Bala

Comment: I'm a little unsure of what you would like to have as key and what should be value, but generally I'm thinking that you should simply use the `map`-function to map the output into your desired key-value pairs and then use `sc.saveAsSequenceFile` to store the file...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am happy to keep the key and values as follows
key -> total_pymnt  value -> 7709668.451690674
key -> purpose  value -> moving
key -> cnt  value -> 2420
.. likewise

Comment: I doesn't make much sense. While getting `Map[String, Any]` for each `Row` it is almost useless for downstream processing.

Comment: ok.. how shall i construct into a Key Value pair from those row of data please.